# Nhibernate Save failure - One to many

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a book object, that has steps. These are reflected in the mapping files and classes below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="DA"
                   namespace="DA">

  <class name="Book" table ="Book">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="Description"  />
    <property name="CreateDate" />
    <property name="ModifiedDate" />
    <property name="AuthorId" />


    <set name="Steps" table="Steps" cascade="all">
      <key column="BookId"/>
      <one-to-many class="Step"/>
    </set>
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="DA"
                   namespace="DA">
  <class name="Step" table ="Steps">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="BookId" />
    <property name="Name"  />
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>


public class Book
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    public virtual int AuthorId { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a test that looks to add a book that fails because of the sub objects steps being added. ***When these are not present it adds the book entry fine.*** It seems there is something wrong with the one to many relationship

```
public void AddBook()
{
    Book b = new Book();
    b.AuthorId = 1;
    b.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
    b.Description = "<Insert book Desription>";
    b.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    b.Name = "<Book Title>";
    b.Steps = new List<Step>();
    b.Steps.Add(new Step() { Name = "Step1" });
}
```

which calls

```
public bool AddBook(Book BookToAdd)
{

    using (var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        this.Session.Save(BookToAdd);
        tx.Commit();
    }

    return true;

}
```

the error I get is

```
GenericADOException was unhandled by user code
could not insert: [DA.Step][SQL: INSERT INTO Steps (BookId, Name) VALUES (?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]

{"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_Steps_Book\". The conflict occurred in database \"Books\", table \"dbo.Book\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

Answer (score 1):

BookId on the step class isn't being set, as such it will try to insert null breaking the FK.

**Define both sides of the relationship**
On the step mapping define bookid on the step class as book and map it as a many to one.

On the book mapping mark the steps one to many as inverse =true. Only mark as inverse on the collection.

Mapping both sides of the relationship let's nhibernate understand the order it needs to insert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `inverse="true"`:

```
<set name="Steps" table="Steps" cascade="all" inverse="true">
  <key column="BookId"/>
  <one-to-many class="Step"/>
</set>
```